# HDMI port has stopped working on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have been using 12.04 LTS with an HDMI monitor for quite some time now and everything has been working wonderfully. However, recently my HDMI port has stopped working, and I have been all over these and other forums without finding a solution.

I know that the the HDMI cable and the monitor aren't the problem because I have swapped out both these pieces of hardware with no change. I am using an HP Envy laptop. The CPU is an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz. I am using that CPUs graphics chip - Intel® HD Graphics 4400. I do not have a dedicated graphics card.

```
:$ xrandr

    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
    eDP1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
    1366x768       60.0*+   40.0  
    1360x768       59.8     60.0  
    1024x768       60.0  
    800x600        60.3     56.2  
    640x480        59.9
```

The above information proves that the system is not aware of the HDMI port hardware, and only the laptops display. It feels to me as if the HDMI port drivers are no longer working.

Might anyone know how to help me fix this? Do I need to reinstall drivers, or install a different kernel?

Comment: So if you go in your System Settings -> Screen Display, you don't see anything to enable the 2nd monitor?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it. I ended up plugging it into a monitor with a lower resolution and was able to then enable the second monitor in the **Systems Settings -> Screen Display** window and then it worked with the original 1080p monitor again.